# Python MYSQLdb how to execute insert with different parameters

Tags: python, insert, mysql-python

How can i perform mysqldb inserts with different parameters?
The example says:

```
add_employee = ("INSERT INTO employees "
               "(first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

data_employee = ('Geert', 'Vanderkelen', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))

cursor.execute(add_employee, data_employee)
```

What I want to do is

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)", ('animals', 'name', 'fox'))
```

but I get an an error

```
MySQL Error [1064]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''animals' ('name') VALUES ('fox')' at line 1
```

I understand the formatter of MYSQLdb is working wrong, is there a way to fix that? And, is it somehow possible to do such thing

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)", ('animals', ('name','color'), ('fox', 'orange'))
```

EDIT: Please don't base your answer on assumption that all inserted data will be strings. I also want to be able to pass BLOB data with these queries

```
imageofafox = open('fox.jpg', 'rb').read()
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.execute(sql, ('animals', 'name, picture', ('fox', imageofafox)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cursor.execute will auto-quote all given parameters, so your query initially could not have been working, because table name and field names where quoted :)

only if you use pythons build-in `%` instead of `,` then you should wrap your values in `'` to make sure:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % ('animals', 'name', "'fox'"))
```

and if you want to include multiple fields and values remember you are passing them as three strings (also numbers and other values are auto-quoted mysql will handle the data typing):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % ('animals', 'name, color', "'fox', 'orange'"))
```

you can test the outcome with print and %

```
print "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % ('animals', 'name, color', "'fox', 'orange'")
```

as far as i know though, you can not pass arrays as a single parameter into execute, only a list of parameters, so `('animals', ['name', 'color'], ...` will not work!

Here is a complete script for testing and figuring out why it won't work in your environment, because it sure does in mine:

```
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='test')
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)"
arg = ('animals', 'name', "'fox'")

cursor.execute('set profiling = 1')
try:
    cursor.execute(sql % arg)
    connection.commit()
except:
    cursor.execute('show profiles')
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
    raise

connection.close()
```

***Explanation***: If you use the `cursor.execute(sql, args)` then the function will auto quote all values. Since your SQL contains not only `%s` for values but also for table name and field names, then you can not let them be auto quoted, otherwise SQL will fail. If you use `cursor.execute(sql % args)` then you have to add the quotes to your values yourself but your query won't fail because table name and field name are not quoted.

Comment: Doesn't work, your first code results in
MySQL Error [1064]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''animals' ('name') VALUES ('\'fox\'')' at line 1

Comment: sorry, forgot the auto-quoting of cursor.execute since i was using it with % and not with , so the error is somewhere else...

Comment: my initial query didn't work, hence the error mentioned in the question

Comment: @ValeraP. you have not read my solution correctly if you use the comma, then table name and field names are placed in `'` which raises your error, use the `%` and add quotes only to value fields then your query works!

Comment: I cannot test it right no but my guess would be (as it is the only and obvious difference) is you are using mysql.connector, whereas I use mysqldb.

Comment: no, no, it does not matter what module you use, your SQL itself has an error, because you have quotes around table name and field name. The only way to come around this is replacing your `,` between sql and args with `%` and then they will not be auto quoted... so engine won't make difference it is pure SQL syntax error

Comment: Yeah, ok, your solution works in my environment as well. It's a shame though one cannot pass some structure, for example tuple or a list, as a parameter for %s, seems it still would be neccesary to take out values one by one and concatenate them to a string. Becomes even more complicated if you you want to add BLOB values, as they are not strings

Answer (score 0):

// Edit: That was meant for java mysql things

Your data is of a wrong type, you need strings or numerical types inside the data tuple.

```
 //data_employee = ('Geert', 'Vanderkelen', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))
 data_employee = ('Geert', 'Vanderkelen', 'no idea what tomorrow was', 'M', 'date(1977, 6, 14)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as your exapmle, if your example is working.

```
add_animals = ("INSERT INTO %s "
                 "(%s) "
                 "VALUES (%s)") 
data_animals = ('animals', 'name', 'fox')
cursor.execute(add_animals, data_animals)
```

Make sure data is committed to the database using `commit()`

Comment: my example is not working, hence the error, mentioned in the question